# 'Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set' when attaching a file

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to scrape a directory for all the files in it, and only attach the most recently modified file.

I have code that will attach files.

I started off with code that is essentially like this

```
Dim JobLocation As String
JobLocation = InputBox("What is the Clients Name ?")
ClientDirectory = "S:\Client Folder\" & JobLocation & "\Site Drawings\"
RequiredPDFs = Dir(ClientDirectory & "*.pdf")
Do While Len(RequiredPDFs) > 0
    .Attachments.Add ClientDirectory & RequiredPDFs
    RequiredPDFs = Dir
Loop
```

I want to adapt the code to find the file that was last modified and only attach that file.

```
Sub Test()

Dim JobLocation As String
Dim objFile As Object
Dim dLastModifiedDate As Date
Dim strLastModifiedFilePath As String
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ClientDirectory As Object

JobLocation = InputBox("What is the Clients Name ?")
ClientDirectory = "S:\Client Folder\" & JobLocation & "\Site Drawings\"

If ClientDirectory.Files.Count > 0 Then
    For Each objFile In ClientDirectory.Files
        If (objFile.DateLastModified > dLastModifiedDate) Then
            strLastModifiedFilePath = objFile.Path
            dLastModifiedDate = objFile.DateLastModified
        End If
    Next

  If strLastModifiedFilePath <> "" Then
      Set objMail = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
      objMail.Attachments.Add strLastModifiedFilePath
  End If
End If

End Sub
```

I expected this to crawl through each file, compare it to the next and then attach that which was the LastModified.

It throws the following error:

> 'Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set'

Answer (score 0):

You treat variable ClientDirectory as an object but in original code it is a simple string. That is why your line :

```
ClientDirectory = "S:\Client Folder\" & JobLocation & "\Site Drawings\"
```

fail.

Also you missed that this variable is used in a Dir operation that store its result in requiredPDFs variable. That is that variable that contains file names.